# What can we say about rank(A)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix}B&C\\D&E\end{pmatrix} $$ where B is a $m \times n$ , C is a $ m \times k$ , D is a $ k \times n$ and E is a $ k \times k$ matrix. If E is an invertible matrix, what can we say about rank(A)?

I just know that the rank of a matrix is equal to the maximum number of linearly independent rows (or columns). I have no idea what to do!

Comment: Chose some examples for $B,C,D$ to see what can happen. For example, with $B=C=D=0$ the rank of $A$ is $k$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:  There are at least as many independent rows for $A$ as in $E$.

Comment: So A has at least k linearly independent rows. Can't we say more about rank(A)?

Comment: So it follows that $\rm{rank}A\ge k$.